# How to show material tab content only if is active?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I trying to show tab content only if is selected:

```
        <mat-tab label="contacts">
            <p-contacts [contacts]="selectedPanel.contacts"
                        *ngIf="tabGroup.selectedIndex === 1">
            </p-contacts>
        </mat-tab>
```

it is work, but i got `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.`
So what do i did wrong?

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wczj1f?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: show us ts file also

Comment: This blog helped me previously when I encountered this https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wczj1f?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html

Comment: your demo code and code in the question are different...plus I'm not sure what you're trying to acheive, what's wrong with the default materials tab? https://stackblitz.com/angular/jrkoremjemy?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html

Comment: @AndrewAllen it is different, but the same problem. i wont to load content to dom only if is active.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can [lazily load the tabs'](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading) content by put the content in `ng-template` with `matTabContent` attribute like this:

```
<mat-tab-group  #tabGroup>
  <mat-tab  label="Firt">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      Content 1
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab  label="Second">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      Content 2
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab  label="Third">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      Content 3
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Yes, good answer but can't find a way to reload the tab every time it is selected through navigation

Comment: @hamzaraissi it's reloading for me. Does exactly what I needed.

Comment: My mistake. i had side effects which made it seem like not reloading. Everything is working now. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score -1):

*ngIf physically changes the DOM by adding or removing the element every time the condition changes. So if the condition changes before it is rendered to the view the error is thrown. 
Adding this will force a change detection cycle after Angular checks the content projected into the directive/component:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';

  constructor(private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {

    this.cdref.detectChanges();

  }
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wczj1f-hrz1ar?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.ts)**

Comment: it is suppress the error, but why should i do this?